# Matrix-based proof of transformation rule for a wedge product of covectors by wedge product of covectors

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, inner-products, tensor-products

I am supposed to show

> $$\beta^1 ∧ ··· ∧ \beta^k = (\det A) \gamma^1 ∧ ··· ∧ \gamma^k$$
>
> for covectors $\beta^1, ···, \beta^k, \gamma^1, ···, \gamma^k$ of a
>   vector space finite dimensional real vector space $V$ of dimension $n$
>   such that $\vec{\beta}=A\vec{\gamma}$, where
>
> $$\vec{\beta} = [\beta^1 ... \beta^k]^T, \vec{\gamma} = [\gamma^1 ...
> > \gamma^k]^T, A = [a_1^T ... a_k^T]^T, a_i^T = [a^i_1 ... a^i_k]$$

The solutions I have found (like [this one on stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290053/transformation-rule-for-a-wedge-product-of-covectors) and two more that are not on stackexchange) are not matrix-based and do not seem to utilize the following fact about the wedge product of covectors

> $$(\beta^1 ∧ ··· ∧ \beta^k) (v_1, ..., v_k) = \det[\beta^{i}(v_j)]$$

- **So I'm composing a matrix-based proof now. Please verify.**

Let $v_1, ..., v_k \in V$. Then $$LHS = (\beta^1 ∧ ··· ∧ \beta^k) (v_1, ..., v_k) = \det[\beta^{i}(v_j)] = \det[\vec{\beta}(v_1) ... \vec{\beta}(v_k)],$$ where $\vec{\beta}(v_j) = [\beta^1(v_j) ... \beta^k(v_j)]^T$.

Now,

$$[\vec{\beta}(v_1) ... \vec{\beta}(v_k)] = [A\vec{\gamma}(v_1) ... A\vec{\gamma}(v_k)] = A [\vec{\gamma}(v_1) ... \vec{\gamma}(v_k)] = A [\gamma^i(v_j)]$$

Therefore,

$$LHS = \det[\vec{\beta}(v_1) ... \vec{\beta}(v_k)] = \det (A [\gamma^i(v_j)])= \det (A) \det([\gamma^i(v_j)])$$

$$ = \det(A) (\gamma^1 ∧ ··· ∧ \gamma^k)(v_1, ..., v_k) = RHS$$

---

- My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. This is Exercise 3.7 and is called "Transformation rule for a wedge product of covectors". The above fact is [Proposition 3.27](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130037/whats-the-difference-between-the-derivations-of-bases-of-a-kv-and-l-kv) called "wedge product of 1-covectors" (covector is defined as 1-covector).
- *Motivation for a matrix-based proof*: I believe there's a way to do a matrix-based proof for another exercise, [Exercise 3.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWZdy.png), based on an analogous result for [Proposition 3.27](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130037/whats-the-difference-between-the-derivations-of-bases-of-a-kv-and-l-kv) and [Exercise 3.1 on inner product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129593/describe-f-in-terms-of-the-tensor-products-of-alphai-and-alphaj-is-th) (specifically the generalization of Exercise 3.1 given in Exercise 3.3). If the above proof is unsuccessful, then I might not continue to attempt a matrix-based proof for Exercise 3.8. If the above proof is successful, then I might consider posting my attempt of a matrix-based proof for Exercise 3.8 in another question.

Comment: are you sure $n\neq k$? If we scale $A$ by a constant $q$, the left-hand side of the equation should scale by $q^k$, yet the right hand side should scale by $det (q*A) / (det A) = q^n$.

Comment: @user3257842 $A$ is $k \times k$ and not $n \times n$, so how did you get $\det(q * A) = q^n \det (A)$ please?

Comment: I got confused when I saw $\vec{\beta}=A\vec{\gamma}$, and took $A$ as an operator that acts on the elements of $V$. However, looking at the definitions, it is more appropriate to say $A$ acts on indices, defining a specific way to obtain the $\beta^q, q\in\{1..k\}$ vectors as index-dependent linear combinations of the $\gamma^q, q\in\{1..k\}$ vectors.

Comment: @user3257842 So, proof is correct?

Comment: @user3257842 Thanks, but what do you mean? Is my proof correct?